# Modify Visual Studio's file templates

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, visual-studio-templates

Everytime I create an *Android Layout* file in Visual Studio (for Xamarin.Android), it gives me a simple layout with a LinearLayout and sets the default namespace of Views to `android`. With time, I found it tiresome and repetitive to write the whole `android` namespace for every View's properties and started to switch it to simply "x", which I was used to when writing some UWP apps (for example, I write `x:id="@+id/SomeId"` instead of `android:id="@+id/SomeId`). Still, I have to make this change every time I create a new layout file, so I'd like to know how can I modify this file template (and any other if it's the same process) so that it'll set the default namespace for Views to "x" instead of "android".

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `android` to `x` in your layout.

Change:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

To:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:x="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    x:orientation="vertical"
    x:layout_width="match_parent"
    x:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        x:layout_width="match_parent"
        x:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I do every time, what I want to change is the template itself so that each time I use it it already has `xmlns:x="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` instead of `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: As i know, we could not do that with a template. We could change it in each layout.